# Windows Service won't install "File Not Found Exception"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service, windows-services

when I try installing my Service I get the following error:

```
Exception Occured while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could Not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\...\bin\Debug\OrionRAService' or one of its dependancies. 
The System cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm installing using visualstudio commandline, and I'm in the correct directory. I know the file exists because I can phisically see it in my file browser.
[image]
Below is my Service's code (at least the parts for a service, anything left out is computations and stuffs):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace OrionRAService
{
   // Define a service contract.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://OrionRAService")]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Profile> CollectAllProfiles();
        [OperationContract]
        bool IsItActive(Profile P);
        [OperationContract]
        void ChangeProfileActivity(Profile p,bool isActive);
        [OperationContract]
        void ChangeDaysToKeepData(int DayCount);
        //[OperationContract]
        //void CollectOnActiveProfiles(DateTime startTake, DateTime endTake);
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Profile
    {
        //... ... ...
    }
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {    
        //implementation of all methods from ICalculator
    }
    public class CalculatorWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        //... ... ...
        public ServiceHost mHost = null;
        //... ... ...
        public CalculatorWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "OrionRAService";
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new CalculatorWindowsService());
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (mHost != null)
            {
                mHost.Close();
            }
            mHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost"));
            mHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "MyServiceAddress");
            mHost.Open();
            //... ... ...
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (mHost != null)
            {
                mHost.Close();
                mHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
    // Provide the ProjectInstaller class which allows 
    // the service to be installed by the Installutil.exe tool
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
        private ServiceInstaller service;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            service = new ServiceInstaller();
            service.ServiceName = "OrionRAService";
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(service);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the App.Config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"
               behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the binary to another directory, and then try to register as a service from that location?

Comment: Could you post the command you used please?

Comment: C:\...\bin\Debug> install.exe OrionRAService.exe

Comment: I think you're missing a dependency, not the actual main service assembly. Look through all of your references, one by one, and check to make sure each one is either in the install folder, or the GAC.  It is also important to make sure they are exactly the same Assembly version.